# showContextMenuForChild in listview adapter - style of contextMenu

Tags: android, listview

I develop application on android 8.1,
I have activity with listview with contextMenu. List item is a group of three elements and one of them is clickable. So for this element contextMenu is not called. For call contextMenu I use:

```
imageView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            parent.showContextMenuForChild(v);

            return true;
        }
    });
```

in adapter getView().

But in this case contextMenu style is Modal-style, but in all application style is popup-style default. How change style in my case to popup.

P.S: I think problem in this showContextMenuForChild, because If call showContextMenuForChild in activity, style of contextMenu is change too  to Modal-style.

Answer (score 0):

```
panel.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    // save the X,Y coordinates
    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        lastTouchDownXY[0] = event.getX();
        lastTouchDownXY[1] = event.getY();
    }

    // let the touch event pass on to whoever needs it
    return false;
}
```

});

```
panel.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        float x = lastTouchDownXY[0];
        float y = lastTouchDownXY[1];
        parent.showContextMenuForChild(v,x ,y);
        //parent.showContextMenu(x + v.getPivotX(),y);
    }

    return true;
}
```

});

first function detect coords of touch, and second set position of contextMenu! Thanks for all.